# Trying to vote to close on closed question displays wrong error message

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

When I try to vote to close a question that already got closed in the meantime, I get the error message:

> You may only load the close dialog every 3 seconds.

[image]

But I definitely did not open the close vote dialog before.

When I reload the page, the question is closed (with the 5th vote of another user).

The message used to be something like this:

> The question is already closed. Please refresh the page.

Comment: It's time to change the mouse... it's clicking twice.

Comment: Reproduced, With a new mouse.

Comment: @Braiam not sure if I want to replace two mouses and a laptop trackpad..

Comment: That happened to me as well a few days ago, so I can confirm that it is reproducible. Just did not raise it on Meta up to now.

Comment: I can reproduce it if I double-click fast...

Comment: @Braiam You can reproduce the message that way because that's what it's for. However the bug described is real.

Comment: Cross-site dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280000/flagging-a-deleted-answer-results-in-a-message-saying-i-am-flagging-too-quickly, likely.

Comment: What is the reason to rate limiting opening a close dialog?

Comment: @EJP well, I've not seen it yet, and I've vtc'ed at least 4 questions where I was the last voter.

Comment: @Braiam *Of course* you won't see it if you're the last voter. You'll see it when it's closed *while you're voting.* I've seen it multiple times, and so have several other people here. And the fact that you can reproduce the correct behaviour has no bearing on whether the incorrect behaviour also exists.

Comment: Exact cross-site dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280019.

Comment: I had the same issue (twice!), but it happened on deleted questions instead. In one case I think I was actually able to flag something as spam after it was deleted already (probably from spam flags), but I saw the message for a split second before the menu popped up.

Comment: I would guess this has to do with some 'state' existing in your browser while it has changed on the server, and that, for whatever reason, your browser state may blindly report that particular error whenever it receives either a.) any error response from the server or b.) particular error responses from the server. Just another example of the intricacies of coordinating client side javascript ajax calls with server side state changes.

Comment: @ButtleButkus Not Really. It's a brand new bug. It used to work correctly.

Comment: @Xufox That's not an 'exact dupe'. It's only related.

Comment: @TylerH Huh? This question is about the wrong 3-second message while a question is actually already closed, the other question is about the 3-second message which appears wrongly where the correct message should be the one about the question already being closed. How is this not the same?

Comment: @Xufox I accidentally clicked through to the target that one was closed as a dupe of and thought I was still reading your comment on MSE.

Comment: Same issue but this also happens when questions are closed rather than deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit 2:** I believe we found the cause of this, please retry now. TL;DR is that our CDN automatically retried GET requests that returned a 500, which is why we saw it in our logs, but you don't see it on your side. We have now disabled that feature so the CDN won't generate a 2nd request.

---

**Edit:** Thanks for your comments. I'm seeing some strange requests in the logs.

Basically when you try to vote-close a question that's already closed, the server returns an HTTP 500 with the "Question already closed" error message. However, we see that your browser makes a second GET request immediately after, which hits the throttling (HTTP 409).

I can't reproduce the second request, for me it only ever makes the first, HTTP 500-returning request. Can you check if there are any browser extensions that might be responsible for this, or try another browser and see if it happens there?

[image: Server Access Logs]

---

**Original:** I've tried to repro this to no avail, I'm getting the correct error message every time unless I indeed vote too fast. I saw that a few of you indeed hit the throttle, but I wonder if this is still happening to any of you regularly, and if you're e.g. behind a company/university proxy?

Comment: It still happens, I just reproduced it twice. And no, I'm not behind a proxy; it's reproducible with 3 different ISPs. Note that it only occurs if the close vote dialog is not yet open (i.e. when you click the "close" link). If you already opened the dialog and then try to submit the close vote, the error message is the correct one.

Comment: Same for me.  The other way give the correct error message.

Comment: This just happened to me a few minutes ago. I saw that exact message, and it was my first close vote today. [The question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999760/can-i-use-c-sharp-instead-of-javascript-web-apps-and-websites) already had 4 close votes, so the final 5th vote likely came in very close to the same time I tried to cast my own vote. I'm sure there's a bug here, but it may be a rare race condition.

Comment: @Floern Thanks, i've updated this posting. Still can't repro, but I do see something strange going on.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thanks. I've updated the post with something strange going on, saw the same 500-response-followed-by-another-call thing

Comment: Running Windows 10x64, Chrome 51. Active browser extensions: Send from Gmail, AdBlock Plus, Cisco WebEx, Add to Amazon Wishlist, Google Docs/Sheets/Slides, Google Docs Offline (I'm responsible for managing the Google Apps for Edu domain for the college where I work). AdBlock Plus seems the most likely to be playing games here.

Comment: @MichaelStum I just reproduced it on Firefox and Chrome without any plugins and incognito mode. I only see one single request in the console that results directly in a 409, I never get a 500.

Comment: And just to share how one can test this: **1)** Find a question with 4 close votes. **2)** Open the question twice (in two tabs). **3)** Vote to close in one tab; now the question is closed. **4)** Try to open the close vote dialog in the other tab (more than 3 seconds later); this now fails with a 409, i.e. one gets the 3 seconds message.

Comment: @Floem I think we found the cause of this and a fix should be live now

Comment: Yep, looks like it's fixed now.